# Не могу подключить Tools при создании проекта LibGDX

Tags: libgdx

Запускаю файл `gdx-setup.jar`, скачанный с официального сайта. Заполняю все поля, генерирую проект:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Открываю в Android Studio файл `build.gradle` и загружаю проект. В проекте не могу подключить пакет `tools`, непосредственно в файле `build.gradle` нету зависимости от `tools`. Зависимость появляется только если вручную записать зависимость в `build.gradle`.

Вопрос - почему поставив галочку напротив `Tools` при создании проекта, я не получаю данный инструмент.